# Get input with QEMU and ARM semi-hosting?

Tags: assembly, arm, qemu

For an ARM architecture, we make *system* calls using the `SVC` instruction.  My reference is the following [ARM's *What is semihosting?*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471c/Bgbjjgij.html). 
In particular, pick any version, select Arm Compiler Toolchain Developing Software ..., then choose Semihosting, to see the available system call numbers.

One wants to define a `getChar()` routine that leaves the `char` in register `r0`.  According to the documentation, `r1` must be 0 upon calling, and after exit `r0` contains the read character.  Thus one thinks that something like,

```
mov r1,#0
mov r0,#7
svc 123456
```

Should be the essential ingredients.  However, the program does not wait for input.  I can also say, for sure, that the register `r0` always contains the value 0 after exiting.  Any thoughts on what is going on?  I suspect the problem lies in understanding what *console* means in the documentation.

Comment: what platform are you on?

Comment: I am on linux x86_64.  However, I am emulating ARM in QEMU through the semi-hosting interface.  The semihosting interface implements the system calls at the link in the post.  The one I am interested in is "SYS_READC"  -- which if called with 0 in r1, is supposed to return a character in r0.  It is 0x07.  You call it through the SVC command which allows the host system to perform the action.

Comment: The swi infrastructure requires a great deal of overhead and is obviously platform specific.  If you want to read input, why not just read it directly?  Despite ARMs illusion, swi, svc, angel, semihosting, whatever they are calling it today, is not the way to go unless you are implementing the system for yourself (you provide both sides), and even there that infrastructure doesnt make much sense to use given the overhead.  It is one way to get out of user mode sure, if you have a system that needs user mode...

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Can you suggest the canonical way to get input directly?  My goal is to have a compiler target the ARM architecture, and I wanted to test it with QEMU -- since that seemed the easiest way to go.

Comment: arm architecture has nothing to do with it, it is platform dependent, you can use swi/svc as a abstraction layer, but somebody has to implement the bottom half that is platform dependent.  arm platforms vary dramatically, so first you need to perhaps pick a class of platform, microcontrollers vs linux capable vs phones, tablets, etc.  even with angel or semihosting or whatever they call it now you still need a platform specific layer.

Comment: there isnt a canonical way, at least I hope not, that would be sad.

Comment: I made this example for someone at some point (coincidentally it uses swi/svc which other than this I rarely to never use) https://github.com/dwelch67/yagbat/blob/master/qemu being a sim world the uart didnt really need setup, could cheat and just shove bytes in to the tx register.  I assume likewise you could simply read the status register and read bytes as well.  platform specific of course, qemu supports many arm platforms you have to match up your software to the hardware.

Comment: I consider swi/svc to be an advanced topic for ARM, esp when you get into the different instruction sets (arm, thumb, thumb2).  Perhaps that is what I was demonstrating with that example as well as demonstrating simple console output on qemu.

Comment: Thank you.  What do you use instead of SVC when working with ARM?  Do you look up the actual platform documentation and implement the backend in that way, or do you call a C-library.  What are the advantages?

Comment: look up the documentation and do a back end in a C library, except for bootstrapping and a few other things there is no reason to get into processor specific code. think linux, ethernet drivers, etc are written in C and no matter whether that same ethernet chip is on an arm system, x86, ppc, mips, etc the same linux driver works as is.  the register/memory read/writes may end up being processor specific depending on the abstraction layer. and as mentioned getting from user mode to supervisor mode may require a specific instruction (like svc). or just cause a protection fault which is common

Comment: to each his own, and others will use different methods, unfortunately dos and spim have put a lot of the world in this assembly operating system mindset which is not required and not the only way to do things.  At the end of the day though if you choose this path SOMEBODY still has to implement the code on the other side of the system call.  arm is not going to write that code other than for boards it claims to support, there are many thousands of times more products out there than arm will support directly that you might want to run your code on.

Comment: my answer would be only use svc/swi in cases where you are in user mode and have to get out to do something, then create a call that way.  (and make a rule to only make that call from a known mode, arm or thumb for example).  The code I write is embedded and trusted and doesnt need a user protection layer, so any of the code can get to anything.  Otherwise I write an application or driver on an operating system which is just C api calls, doesnt matter what processor, just matters what operating system.

Comment: Can you out-line what your final goal is? You might be better off forgetting about semi-hosting completely, just compiling for ARM Linux and allowing QEMU to broker the system calls to your native x64 kernel.

Answer (score 3):

From the qemu 1.4.0 source: (file `target-arm/arm-semi.c`, lines 303-305)

```
case TARGET_SYS_READC:
   /* XXX: Read from debug console. Not implemented.  */
    return 0;
```

I suggest you use SYS_READ with a buffer size of 1 instead, if you really want to use qemu's semihosted mode and read from the 'console'.